# perform a function on all the objects at once (without a for loop)

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Is it possible to perform a function on all the objects of a class at once without using a for loop? For example in the following code:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class CTest {
            public:

            int X;

            void clear() {
                X = 0;
            }

    };

    int main() {
        CTest A[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            A[i].X = 10;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            A[i].clear();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

is it possible to do something like `A.X = 10` to initialize all the objects at once or for example use `A.clear()` to clear all the objects at once? I think it is possible to use `<vector>` for this purpose but is there any other way?

Comment: You can't, there has to be loop _somewhere_. Even if you call a function such as [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) there is still a loop (you just won't have it in your code).

Comment: *"At once"*? That would only look like a constant time expression, while it would still take O(n) operations. It's possible to do something like this in a single expression, but there's no magic trick to do everything _at once_. There will be a loop somewhere.

Comment: @Zeta Well it could _theoretically_ be done at once, if using e.g. 100 threads on a 100+ core CPU... :)

Comment: If you want to save typing then use constructor with default argument like `CTest(int i=10):X(i){}`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: We would still have to create those 100 threads, and since we want to associate each object with a thread... ;)

Comment: "I would like to go to the store 20 times, but all at once".  does that make sense to you?

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are trying to solve when asking this question?

Comment: When we create an array like `CTest A[100]`. The default constructor is anyway invoked 100 times. I am wondering why there isn't any convenient syntax like `CTest A(10)[100]` i.e. it should call that constructor for all the objects which takes an int like `CTest(int i):X(i){}`. Or is there? With vector we can do that.

Comment: @AbhijitKadam: but even in that case you woud simply be delegating the loop to a library.  It would still need to call your constructor N times.  It's like thinking your loop over a string which calls `strlen` in the condition is linear in time because you only *see* a single loop.

Comment: @Ed S, I did not think of the loop to be avoided like the O.P who has asked this question. I was thinking of running the constructors N times with proper initialization rather than N times during `CTest A[100];`and then again to initialize.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  You need to perform some operation N times?  Well, at *best*, that's a linear time operation.  You are never going to get constant time out of it, ever.  It just doesn't make sense to expect anything else.

Comment: When we create an array like `CTest A[100];`. The default constructor is anyway invoked 100 times. I am wondering why there isn't any convenient` syntax like `CTest A(10)[100]` i.e. it should call that constructor for all the objects which takes an int like `CTest(int i):X(i){}`. Or is there? With vector we can do that.

Comment: @AbhijitKadam: vector uses the copy constructor and a different allocater.  It never uses the default constructor.  You can achieve something similar using `placement new` (or just look at how `vector` does it of course) , but I have to ask... why don't you just use a vector and save yourself the headache?

Comment: Thanks, I know about vector and I am fine with that. Because of the question I was wondering if there is some way with array to do that in core language though not really required anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::for_each from STL algorithm header with arrays. Instead of iterators begin()/end() you can pass CTest* pointers 'array' and 'array + size' or better std::begin(A)/std::end(A). The only problem is calling a non static member such as clear(). If you have C++11 use lambdas or else check out STL functional or boost bind.

```
//C++11 code:
#include <algorithm>
std::for_each(std::begin(A),std::end(A),[](CTest& ct){ct.X = 10;});
std::for_each(std::begin(A),std::end(A),[](CTest& ct){ct.clear();});
```

edited: use begin/end for arrays instead of pointer arithmetics

Comment: There are std::begin/end functions for arrays